# A line integral/Green's Theorem problem

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-fields, greens-theorem

I'm stuck on the following problem:

Let $f(x,y) = -\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}$ and $g(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}$ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Show that
$$\oint_{\partial S} (f(x,y) \,dx + g(x,y)\,dy) = 2\pi $$
if $S$ is any open set in the plane containing $(0,0)$ with $\partial S$ as its boundary.

**My attempt:** 
This looks like a Green's Theorem problem to me, so that was the first thing I tried:
\begin{align*}
\oint_{\partial S} (f(x,y) \,dx + g(x,y)\,dy) &= \iint_S \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) \,dx \,dy.
\end{align*}

I found that
\begin{align*}
  & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(-\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} \right) = \frac{y^2-x^2}{x^2+x^2}.
\end{align*}

Thus, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, and so the integral vanishes. Clearly I'm doing something wrong if the answer is supposed to be $2 \pi$...Where did I go wrong with this?

Comment: Green's Theorem only applies to functions with continuous partial derivatives on $S$.

Comment: Most textbooks will have a section on how to apply Green's theorem to non simply connected regions (ones with holes in them). I suggest you take a look at yours.